# jQuery - OnClick, change background color for table cells

Tags: jquery, cell

Let me show you a demo: [here](http://jsbin.com/ajalu/2)

it is working for only rows. its not working for cells. i want to change cells' (tds') background colors with mouse clicks.

For example: a have a table, and it has 4 tds. table's background color is white. if i click to a td, a td should be red, than if i click to b, b td should be red and a td should be white again. if i click to c than, c should be red and b should be white right now.

A - B

C - D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try updating the JavaScript to:

```
$( function() {
  $('td').click( function() {
    $(this).parents('table').find('td').each( function( index, element ) {
        $(element).removeClass('on');
    } );
    $(this).addClass('on');
  } );
} );
```

[**Preview**](http://jsbin.com/ajalu/40)

Comment: omg,such a perfect and fast answer. this answer helped me very well. thank you.

Comment: -1 I doubt he wants to bind EVERY td on click... this would bind every td. additionally, it doesn't bind td's created AFTER render. you should use .live when you want to bind anything really

Comment: Seth: I just happened to update a bit of what was already there. The person who asked the question never said that there will be a possibility of future `td` s being generated or that only one `table` 's `td` should be affected.

Comment: andrew: Glad that you found my answer helpful. If so, you could select my answer and upvote it.

Comment: +1 this satisfies the user's request. The idea is already here and its up to the user how he explore this idea.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having the line:

```
$(this).addClass("on").parent().siblings("tr").find("td").removeClass("on");
```

you could just store which is the colored cell and remove the class without having to search, like this:

```
var light = null;
$(function(){
  $("td").click(function(){
     if(light) { light.removeClass("on"); }
     light = $(this);
     light.addClass("on");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML: add a class to the table:

```
<table class="color_changing">...</table>
```

jQuery:

```
$('table.color_changing tr td').live('click', function(){
  $(this).parent().parent().each('td', function(){
    $(this).removeClass('red');
  });

  $(this).addClass('red');
});
```

should work!

Answer (score 0):

How about if you do this?

```
<script>$(function(){
  $("td").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("on").siblings().removeClass("on");
  });
});</script>
```

It will do the same effect with the other TD cells in the same row. Or do you want a cell lighting up to turn off all other cells on the table, no matter the row?